# Vue utils - Check if a method is being called with jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I am doing some tests and I want to check if a method is called after I trigger a click in an element, but the test keeps saying that is wasn't called and I don't know why

Here is my test:

```
test('some test', () => {
        const somethingChanged= jest.spyOn(Component.methods, 'somethingChanged')

        const wrapper = mount(Component, {
            propsData: data

        })

        const element= wrapper.find('.c-element').trigger('click')

        expect(somethingChanged).toBeCalled()
    })
```

This keeps saying that the number of calls is 0 and I don't know what I'm doing wrong
This method is triggered in the component so I know it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [`trigger` documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#trigger) states,

> Triggers an event asynchronously on the Wrapper DOM node.

It should be:

```
const element= wrapper.find('.c-element').trigger('click')
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
expect(somethingChanged).toBeCalled()
```

The use of `await` assumes that test function should be `async`.